# How to integrate CLSTM library in Android application?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm working on a project that requires me to integrate [CLSTM library](https://github.com/tmbdev/clstm) (a C++ implementation of LSTM networks for OCR) in an Android application. I'm a beginner Android developer and this is my first time working with NDK.

I'm having trouble integrating the C++ code with my project. I have been trying to do it for a couple of days, but have still gotten nowhere. I have been looking for solutions everywhere, but I can't find exact instructions for my problem.

What I have been able to do till now is:

1. Created new project with C++ support
2. Downloaded Android NDK
3. Downloaded CMake
4. Created JNI Folder
5. Cloned the source code into JNI Folder

I am not sure if I was supposed to do steps 4, 5 above. Also, from all the tutorials I have found, I think after these I am supposed to create an Android.mk and Application.mk files. I'm not sure what to write in them.

Can anyone guide me with exact steps for how to integrate this particular [library](https://github.com/tmbdev/clstm) in my Android application?

Comment: were you able to compile that library and got an .SO file out of it? if yes, your Android.mk should be pretty simple. https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what exact problem you are having but I'll give it a shot as I've been dabbling with this myself recently. These are the steps I took:

1. Using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0` as my build tools version
2. Added the C libraries in my `app/src/main/jni` directory
3. Added an `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` file in my `app/src/main/jni` directory
4. Added the following to my `app/build.gradle`:

```

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

```

You can find the contents of my `Application.mk` and `Android.mk` [here](https://github.com/JordyLangen/vaultbox).
I based my setup of the `.mk` files & contents upon the [keepassdroid](https://github.com/bpellin/keepassdroid) project.

Edit:

if you also want to use travis-ci you can use this to download and use the android ndk in your builds:

```
before_install:
  - curl -L http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r14-linux-x86_64.zip -O
  - unzip -q android-ndk-r14-linux-x86_64.zip
  - export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=`pwd`/android-ndk-r14
  - export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}
```